# What should I set as the hostname of Couchbase server?

Tags: amazon-ec2, couchbase, hostname

In Couchbase 4.0, while initially setting up, I have a field to enter hostname.

I am working on amazon EC2 and use the public DNS as the hostname. This works but every time I shut and restart the instance, my public DNS changes, which renders the entire configuration useless. Can you please suggest what I should do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to survive the scenario you give, the best option is to not use the EC2 generated public names, but create your own FQDNs in Route53 or another DNS service.